# Remove P tags from images

Tags: images, tags

I'm using WordPress 4.2.2 and every time I add an image to the wysiwyg it wraps the outputed image in a paragraph tag. I need to strip out these tags. Everything I seem to find online is from 2011 plus it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried putting things in the functions.php like:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
  return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Nothing seems to work. How can I accomplish this.

BTW I am using ACF Pro's wysiwyg and JointsWP starter theme and my images ARE NOT wrapped in a link tag if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) Filter wpautop() with ACF:**

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

If you have both of those try checking with a later priority on the add_filter. It's possible the theme or plugin or acf is overriding you....

```
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images', 9999);
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images', 9999);
```

**2) Edit wpautop():**

```
<?php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_wpautop' );
function custom_wpautop() {
 // copy wpautop() code at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L373 and add img to the $allblocks variable
}
```

**3) This above is a lot of code for one task however. Consider trying this:**
https://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup-plus

**4) You could try this although not as good as the method you're trying to accomplish since this one is done with javascript.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('p > img').unwrap();
});
</script>
```

**5) if it's just the styling that's messing things up and you don't care about the markup:**

```
<style type="text/css">
p > img {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The first option works now also for ACF wysiwyg as far as effecting it but it doesn't show any content. Its all blank on the output so I just used the jQuery way.

Comment: Glad one of them worked! I have acf installed on a couple of my sites so I'll test it out when I get a chance.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't need `add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');` when using `add_filter('acf_the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');`

Answer (score 0):

I use the acf_the_content filter to preg_replace the p tag. The below code will replace the p tag and wrap the image inside a div

```
/**
 * Remove P tags from images
 */
function ns_img_unautop($custom_content) {
   $custom_content = preg_replace('/<p>\\s*?(<a .*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '<div class="figure">$1</div>', $custom_content);
   return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'ns_img_unautop', 30 );
```