# Edit default image attachment size

Tags: attachments, images

I am building a theme and I use `single.php` also for attachments.
The problem is that Wordpress print automatically the images with `the_content()` in this way:

```
<p class="attachment">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dsc20040724_152504_532.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dsc20040724_152504_532-300x225.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" srcset="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dsc20040724_152504_532-300x225.jpg 300w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dsc20040724_152504_532.jpg 640w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" width="300" height="225">
    </a>
</p>
```

I would like to have images in full size, but I cannot find the right hook.

Comment: You can use `the_content` combined with `is_attachment()` function.

Comment: do you mean using if statements?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\s*()?\s*()\s*()?\s*/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/\s*(*.)\s*/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

this also has been solved here 
[remove p tags from images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195087/remove-p-tags-from-images)

Comment: The question is about to change attachment image size from medium to original, but thanks anyway

Comment: @ClaudioKing ok did you solve it?

Comment: no, i left it on todo list

Comment: @ClaudioKing when I get off work I'll send you a fix for it. Question are you using the_content only for the image or there will be other content as well such as text?

Comment: I use the_content also for other single attachments, if you have a better solution tell me. Thank you